# Can I use a builtin name as a method name of a Python class?

Tags: python, pep8

I have a class that performs some simple data manipulation, I need three methods: set, add, sub:

```
class Entry():  # over-simplified but should be enough for the question
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.set(value)
    def set(self, value):
        self.value=value
    def add(self, value):
        self.value += value
    def sub(self, value):
        self.value -= value
```

The problem is with the "set" method but defining it as a class method should not clash with the "set()" builtin function.

The [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) states that argument names of functions and methods should not shadow built-in functions, but it's this the case for method names?

Obviously I could choose another method name, but the question is more generic and valid for other possible method names (i.e. filter, sum, input).

Comment: Shouldn't really be a problem, since method names always qualified in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole thing about not shadowing builtin names is that you don't want to stop your self from being able to use them, so when your code does this:

```
x.set(a) #set the value to a
b = set((1,2,3)) #create a set
```

you can still access the builtin `set` so there is no conflict, the only problem is if you wanted to use `set` **inside the class definition**

```
class Entry():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.set(value)
    def set(self, value):
        self.value=value
    possible_values = set((1,2,3,4,5)) #TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

Inside the class definition - and there only - is the built in name shadowed, so you have to consider which you would rather settle for: the unlikely scenario where you need to use `set` to define a class scope variable and get an error or using a non-intuitive name for your method.

Also note that if you like using method names that make sense to you and also want to use `set` in your class definition you can still access it with `builtins.set` for python 3 or `__builtin__.set` for python 2.

Answer (score 1):

You are fine.  You just don't want to overwrite the built-ins if they are a built-in method *__init__* *__iter__* etc unless you are implementing the functionality expected by those methods.

You are "overwriting" a built in *function* as a class method, which means you aren't really overwriting anything.  This is acceptable.

Comment: "if they are a built-in method" confuses me, I think the terminology is that `__init__` and `__iter__` etc are **magic methods** (in that they are called implicitly in certain scenarios)

Comment: that is true.  However, some people don't like calling them magic methods because they aren't magical, AKA you can overwrite them or create them in your own classes and they will work as you write them.  Hence, if you make an object with an `__iter__` method it is considered an *iterable* by python and can be used anywhere an iterable is normally used.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I could have said dunder methods and that might have been clearer.  I was trying to use terminology that fit with the question.  That might not have been the best decision.

Answer (score 1):

[Namespaces are one honking great idea](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - same in this case, name `set` defined but it exists only in namespace limited to `Entry` class and does not clash with built-in function name.