# django context not rendering in html

Tags: python, django

Hi I have 'easy' problem with context in django ;/

I try to send context to render and show it in html page but it dosen't showing.

```
urls
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('viki/main', views.vikimain, name='vikimain'),
```

```
views

@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'project/home.html')

@login_required(login_url='login')
def vikimain(request):
    dict = {'test': 'test'}
    return render(request, 'project/main.html', dict)
```

```
main.html

{% extends 'project/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>{{ dict }}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your context variable is named `test`, why do you use `{{ dict }}`?

Comment: omg how i dont see it -.- hahaha thanks :)

Comment: Also have in mind that shadowing builtin names (`dict` in your example) is not a good practice, [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229951/can-i-use-a-builtin-name-as-a-method-name-of-a-python-class)

Answer (score 0):

if you want use **dict** in your template you must use:

```
return render(request, 'project/main.html', {'dict':dict})
```

then dict show your object

```
<div>{{ dict.test }}</div>
```